# replace Microsoft Teams SRTP Key with my own

Tags: cryptography, microsoft-teams

I would like to replace the cryptographic key used in the Microsoft Teams by my own.
I am thinking about the master SRTP key, the web client or the stand alone one on Microsoft Windows.

I guess it is somewhere inside the javascript code (on the web client)  ?

Is it possible, or is it protected in some way ? Where is it located ? Is there an api to get/set it ?

Comment: I've seen there is a BYOK 5Bring Your Own Key) available for Teams. But this is only used for Teams still data stored in Azure (chat conversation, audio recording, etc.) Is there a way to get it for Audio/Video live meetings. From API, or from a hack ? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not really possible.

I think you are asking to wrong question.
If you want the audio/video streams for a meeting call, there is only one way:

Create a [stateful call bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/requirements-considerations-application-hosted-media-bots) using the [Cloud communications API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communications-concept-overview).

The problem is getting the bot into the call to see the streams.  Either the bot "starts" the call or the bot has to be invited into the call somehow.  The how is up to you.

The other option is to use the [Teams policy-based recording](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-recording-policy) to get your bot invited into the call as part of call setup.  Becareful of this option as it does come with a overhead.  One to one calls will now go through the conference server to allow the third leg to be involved in the call.  This I have found to have call startup overhead.

Comment: I think I don't understand something. Maybe I'am wrong but I don't want to stream nor to record something. I want Microsoft Teams to be using my own cryptographic key, during its SRTP encrypt/decrypt .

Comment: You are assuming a lot of implementation details here.  Microsoft don't document what they use as the audio stream (e.g. if they even use SRTP).  I don't see why you want to do what you want to do unless you want to break there security for recording / listening.  If you want to do that you ask, you will have to hack all there clients and figure it out yourself.  Noone will help with that.

Comment: You do know that SRTP keys are randomally generated when the SDP is generted per side?  My guess is that there will be no "BYOK" for it.  Looking at "BYOK" it looks like it's for "Stored" things like chat logs, recording.  I can't see how they would apply to SRTP which is the live media streams.  Microsoft seems to "record" live media streams by there conference server only, so they are in the media path.